# I'm getting the same message multiple times when using React. Does this mean I'm loading React multiple times?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, serverside-javascript

In my console I get this message 3 times when I load a page:

> Download the React DevTools for a better development experience: https://fb.me/react-devtools

Since it's appearing 3 times does this mean I am loading React 3 times?

Please note, I am doing server side rendering.

Comment: you'll need to provide some context. What's the message? If you inspect the raw page source, do you see react loaded three times. Or, if you check the file which you're loading react in, does it contain three instances of react?

Comment: @Seth The message is listed above regarding React DevTools. The file only contains one instance of React, but React is weird and sometimes bugs out when the same React file is called multiple times. How do I see the raw page source?